# Is this argument valid without premise 1.1?

Tags: logic

Source: 11 mins 49 s juncture, [Lecture 3-7](https://class.coursera.org/thinkagain-005/lecture/276) ([transcription](https://class.coursera.org/thinkagain-005/lecture/subtitles?q=276_en&format=txt)), *... How to Reason and Argue*,
by Prof W Sinnott-Armstrong. 
Caution: My enumeration differs from the Prof's. 
For brevity, I abbreviate 'anything
else that rattles when shaken' with definition 2 of the noun 'rattler'.

> 1. This box rattles when I shake it.
>   1.1. A box doesn't rattle when shaken if it 
>   contains only a  sweater and not any other rattler.
>    <sup>Original:  A box doesn't rattle when shaken if it 
>   contains only a  sweater and not anything else that makes a
>   rattling noise when shaken.</sup> 
>   1.2. If this box contains a sweater, then it
>   contains only
>   a sweater, and doesn't contain any other rattler.
>    <sup>Original: If this box contains a sweater, then it
>   contains only
>   a sweater, and doesn't contain anything
>   else that rattles when shaken.</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 2. So this box does not contain a sweater.

At the 9 mins 32 s juncture, the Prof did not introduce 1.3 yet (I inserted it above to save space, but apologise if it deceives). He explains that without 1.3, the argument is INVALID:

> Well, no, for the same reason we saw
>   before, because my wife might be a
>   trickster
>   who puts rocks around my sweater in the
>   birthday present box, in order to fool me.
>   Then, the premises can be true, and the
>   conclusion, false.

My question: Is the argument valid if we delete 1.1, and keep only and 1.2?

Answer (score 1):

We have :

1) Is_a_box(a) **and** Rattles_when_shaken(a)

1.1) For_all(x) [ **if** Is_a_box(x), **then** (*if* Contains_only_a_sweater_and_nothing_else(x), *then* **not** Rattles_when_shaken(x)) ]

We apply [Universal Instantiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) with the term **a** to 1.1 getting :

2) **if** Is_a_box(a), **then** (*if* Contains_only_a_sweater_and_nothing_else(a), *then* **not** Rattles_when_shaken(a)

from 1) by [Simplification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) (or *conjunction elimination*) we derive :

3.1) Is_a_box(a)

and

3.2) Rattles_when_shaken(a)

with 3.1 and 2, by *modus ponens*, we derive :

4) *if* Contains_only_a_sweater_and_nothing_else(a), *then* **not** Rattles_when_shaken(a)

from 4 by [Contraposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) (with *double negation*) we derive :

5) *if* Rattles_when_shaken(a), *then* **not** Contains_only_a_sweater_and_nothing_else(a)

from 3.2 and 5, again by *modus ponens*, we conclude with :

> **not** Contains_only_a_sweater_and_nothing_else(a).

But the denial of : "the box does not contain only a sweater and nothing else" (using De Morgan) is :

> > "either the box **a** does not contain a swater, or it contain a sweater and something else".

---

Thus, in order to conclude with :

> the box **a** does not contain a sweater

we need an additional premise, in order to apply [Disjunctive syllogism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism) to the disjunction :

> either the box **a** does not contain a swater, or it contain a sweater and something else.

This additional premise must be the denial of :

> the box **a** does contain a sweater and something else;

the negation of **(p∧q)** is **(¬p ∨ ¬q)** as well as **(p → ¬q)**, and thus the additional premise must be :

> *if* the box **a** does contain a sweater, *then* it does not contain something else

that is 1.2 above.